# A Bresenham algorithm implementation[NASM]

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bresenham

I am working on a nasm program that will draw random shapes. I started off with this code, but every time i compile it, I get the error

> bresen.asm:8: error: comma expected after operand 1

Here is the code::

```
segment stack stack
        resb 100 ;declares a stack segment containing 64 bytes of uninitialised stack space, and points stacktop at the top
stacktop:

        segment data

        dex dw 0
        dy dw 0
        x_add dw 0
        y_add dw 0
        maxd dw 0
        act_dx dw 0
        act_dy dw 0
        c dw 0
        x1 dw 0
        y1 dw 0
        x2 dw 0
        y2 dw 0

        segment code
start:
        mov ax,data
        mov ds,ax
        mov ax,stack
        mov ss,ax
        mov sp,stacktop
          mov bp,stacktop

        ;init finished

        mov ah,0h
        mov al,13h
        int 10h

        ;screen set

        mov ax,word 200
        push ax          ;y2
        mov ax,word 50
        push ax          ;x2
        mov ax,word 20
        push ax          ;y1
        mov ax,word 65
        push ax          ;x1
        call line

        ;line(x1,y1,x2,y2)

        xor ax,ax
        int 16h

        ;wait key

        mov ah,0
        mov al,3
        int 10h

        ;go back to text mode

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h

        ;end

line:
        push bp
        mov bp,sp
        mov ax,[bp+4] ;<-1 here
        mov [y2],ax
        mov ax,[bp+6]
        mov [x2],ax
        mov ax,[bp+8]
        mov [y1],ax
        mov ax,[bp+10]
        mov [x1],ax

        ;init-line end here!!!

        mov ax,[x2]
        sub ax,[x1]
        cmp ax,0
        jnl abs1
        neg ax
abs1:   mov [dex],ax

        ;dex=abs(x2-x1)

        mov ax,[y2]
        sub ax,[y1]
        cmp ax,0
        jnl abs2
        neg ax
abs2:   mov [dy],ax

        ;dy=abs(y2-y1)

        mov ax,[x1]
        cmp ax,[x2]
        jl min
        mov [x_add],word -1
        jmp end
min:    mov [x_add],word 1
end:
        ;if (x1>x2)

        mov ax,[y1]
        cmp ax,[y2]
        jl min2
        mov [y_add],word -1
        jmp end2
min2:   mov [y_add],word 1
end2:
        ;if (y1>y2)

        mov ax,[dy]
        cmp ax,[dex]
        jl min3
        mov ax,[dy]
        mov [maxd],ax
        jmp end3
min3:   mov ax,[dex]
        mov [maxd],ax
end3:

        mov cx,[maxd]
here:   mov ax,[dy]
        add [act_dy],ax
        mov ax,[act_dy]
        cmp ax,[maxd]
        jl next
        mov ax,[maxd]
        sub [act_dy],ax
        mov ax,[y_add]
        add [y1],ax
next:   mov ax,[dex]
        add [act_dx],ax
        mov ax,[act_dx]
        cmp ax,[maxd]
        jl next2
        mov ax,[maxd]
        sub [act_dx],ax
        mov ax,[x_add]
        add [x1],ax
next2:  call plot
        loop here
        mov sp,bp
        pop bp
        ret 8

plot:
        push ax
        push bx
        push cx
        push dx
        mov ah,0ch
        mov dx,[y1]
        mov cx,[x1]
        mov al,0d0h     ;change this to change the point-color
        mov bh,0h
        int 10h
        pop dx
        pop cx
        pop bx
        pop ax
        ret
```

I tried to find out why, but it has me stalled for a long while. I will greatly appreciate any feedback or queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DY` is a directive in NASM syntax, so you can't use it as a symbol name.

Comment: Thanks. I made a change to that, but after that, I am now faced with the following errors:

>bresen.asm:1: warning: Unknown section attribute 'stack' ignored on declaration of section `stack'
>bresen.asm:2: warning: uninitialized space declared in non-BSS section `stack': zeroing
>bresen.asm:22: error: symbol `data' undefined
>bresen.asm:24: error: symbol `stack' undefined


I am using [dey] instead of [dy]

Comment: Which output format are you using. AFAIK, `segment name` is valid for `-f obj`.

Comment: I am using the default commands;

-f elf bresen.asm
then use gcc to link and finally run \bresen

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Well, which OS are you targeting?

Comment: Linux - Running on Ubuntu. I have the gcc compiler installed.

Comment: That's not going to work. You've written 16-bit real-mode code (which is also using DOS-specific interrupts). Linux programs run in protected mode, and do not use memory segmentation.

Comment: I am a little lost for words. I tried working on windows, but that proved to be impossible to run the nasm environment there, so I had to switch to Linux. I'd have to re-structure my code to suit this environment, or what are you saying?

Comment: NASM works fine on Windows. However, if you write DOS programs with it you'll have to run them in an emulator (like DOSBox). If you want to program for Linux you'll have to use the appropriate OS calls and memory model. An introduction to Linux programming (or programming for any OS) is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question though.

Comment: Thanks. I found an article that I will follow up on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45788/The-Real-Protected-Long-mode-assembly-tutorial-for?PageFlow=Fluid